# What effect is expected if LoRA is applied after Fine-tuning?

Tags: transformer, fine-tuning

I am currently learning several things about the ASR Transformer model.
Recently, I learned LoRA and Adapter.
It certainly seems to have an advantage over fine-tuning in general.

But here I came up with an interesting idea.
For example, if fine-tune an ASR model with specific speech data, and apply LoRA again to the generated model, what effect can you expect?

For instance, after fine-tuning an ASR with voices of the elderly only, what effects can we expect if we then apply LoRA using voices of the elderly with laryngeal disorders only?

Thank you for reading.